# PhpUnit: The http response is empty though test is carried out fine

Tags: php, codeigniter, unit-testing, phpunit

I am trying to write unit tests for practice on a small application. This is my first time with unit-tests and I have not a very good knowledge. This is what I am trying to do.

```
$response=$this->request('POST',['crud_controller','add_data' ,$data]);
$this->assertEquals(1,$response);
```

The function `add_data` is programmed to `return 1` if the data is processed or `return -1` otherwise. The data is getting processed but phpUnit shows failed test with 
issue:

> Failed asserting that null matches expected 1.

I am working in **codeigniter** and using **phpunit** for testing.

**Complete Test-Case:**

```
    <?php
    class crud_controller_test extends TestCase{
    public function test_add_data(){
        $data =array(
            'name' => 'badPass',
        );
        $response=$this->request('POST',['crud_controller','add_data' ,$data]);
        $this->assertEquals(1,$response);
        //$this->assertEquals(-1,$response);
        //$this->assertEquals(0,$response);
    }
    public function test_update_data(){
        $data =array(
            'id'=>'29',
            'name' => 'badPass',
        );
        $response=$this->request('POST',['crud_controller','update_data' ,$data]);
        var_dump($response);
        $this->assertEquals(1,$response);
        //$this->assertEquals(-1,$response);
        //$this->assertEquals(0,$response);
    }
}
?>
```

**Methods getting called:**

```
public function add_data($data){

        if($this->crud_model->insert($data) ==true)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
         //return $this->crud_model->insert($data);
        //$this->index();
    }

public function update_data($data){

        if($this->crud_model->update($data) == true)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
        //$this->index();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your hole test case along with the request method which you are calling?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Where is `request` method?

Comment: request is built-in `phpunit` method.

Comment: Ideally you need to mock the request object so that it doesn't call the actual model's method. you can take a look of documentation to see how mocking and stubbing works https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs

Comment: Why request is returning  null?